# TS with Express error with trying to send responde

Tags: typescript, express

I trying to make an API to my Web Applications. I have an error when i trying to send response.

index.js

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
const router = require('express').Router();

router.get('/', function (req: Request, res: Response) {
  res.status(200)
  .send({
    message: 'Success',
    status: res.status,
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

And here is the Error
`This expression is not callable.   Type 'Number' has no call signatures. TS Error`

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

EDIT: I added 1 line and now i don't have this error but I can't read this page when i turn on the server.

Comment: Apparently `res` is not of a `Response` type but a primitive `number` type.

Comment: Are you sure you have to call `.Router()`? Following https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html this is different...

Comment: Now i add import {  Request, Response } from 'express'; and i dont have this error but when i open this i cant get into this page.